# Why are my elements overlapping when I resize the page. I am using percentages

Tags: html, css

Whenever I resize my html page elements start to overlap each other. I have tried to avoid this by using percentages rather than pixels wherever I can. Here is my code of what I have so far, any ideas? How do you like the design btw? :) What's weird is that the vertical line in the middle is where it is supposed to be when the window is resized, but everything else is not.

```css
*:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    
        body {
     background: #ced4da;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    
        .login-box {
     width: 300px;
     height: 170px;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     color: white;
     top: 50%;
     left: 33%;
     position: absolute;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding-top: 12.5px;
        }
    
        .email-input-field {
     position: relative;
        }
    
        .password-input-field {
       position: relative;
        }
    
       .email-input-field i {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 4px;
     padding: 9px 8px;
     color:darkgrey;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .password-input-field i {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 4px;
     padding: 9px 12px;
     color:darkgrey;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
       .email-input-field input:focus + i, .password-input-field input:focus + i {
      color:dodgerblue;
        }
    
        .login-box .email-input-field, .password-input-field {
       margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    
       .login-box input[type="email"], input[type="password"] {
      border: none;
      background: white;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 83%;
      padding-left: 50px;
       }
    
        .login-box input[type="submit"] {
      border: none;
      background-color: #3DBB96;
      color: white;
      outline: none;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: lighter;
        }
    
       ::placeholder {
        color: grey;
       }
    
        .vertical-line {
         border-left: 1px solid darkgrey;
         width:1px;
         height: 170px;
         top: 50%;
         left:50%;
         position:absolute;
         transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }
    
        .side-text {
       top: 50%;
          left:63%;
          position:absolute;
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          line-height: 100%;
        }
    
        .side-text p {
       font-weight: lighter;
        }
    
        .side-text h1 {
       font-weight: normal;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title> Admin Login </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class = "login-box">
      <form>
       <div class = "email-input-field">
        <input type = "email" name = "emailPost" placeholder = "Email">
        <i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
       </div>
       <div class = "password-input-field">
        <input type = "password" name = "passwordPost" placeholder = "Password">
        <i class = "fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
       </div>
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class = "vertical-line"></div>
     <div class = "side-text">
      <h1> COLD OPS </h1>
      <p> ADMINISTRATION PANEL </p>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which elements overlap?

Comment: @TerryCarmen The line overlaps with the login form and side text divs

Answer (score 0):

When making responsive web pages, add the following  element in all your web pages: (inside the head tags)
Example

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```